# Not able to receive File name in server sent by client

Tags: sockets

I am trying to write a simple socket program which reads a file name in client and sends it to the server. The contents of file are sent to the Client back if present. The client and server are able to successfully able to connect but when I read a file name I don't get any output(program doesn't terminates). Please tell me what is going wrong.

server.c

```
int main()
{
int create_socket,new_socket,fd,addlen,n;
int bufsize=1024;
char *buffer=malloc(bufsize);
char fname[255];
struct sockaddr_in address;

//printf("program");    
if((create_socket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))>0)
printf("socket created");

address.sin_family=AF_INET;
address.sin_port=htons(15000);
address.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;

if(bind(create_socket,(struct sockaddr*)&address,sizeof(address))==0)
printf("socket binded");
    while(1)

{
    printf("Inside while loop");
    listen(create_socket,3);
    addlen=sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    if(new_socket=accept(create_socket,(struct sockaddr*)&address,&addlen)>0)
    printf("%d connected",inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr));
    else
    printf("not connected");

    recv(new_socket,fname,255,0);
    printf("file name is %s",fname);
    if(fd=open(fname,O_RDONLY)<0)
    {
        strcpy(buffer,"Not such file found");
        send(new_socket,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);
    }
    else
    {
        while(n=read(fd,buffer,bufsize)>0)
        send(new_socket,buffer,n,0);
    }
    close(new_socket);
}
close(create_socket);

}
```

client.c

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
int create_socket,n;
int bufsize=1024;
char *buffer=malloc(bufsize);
char fname[255];
struct sockaddr_in address;

if((create_socket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))>0)
printf("socket created\n");

address.sin_family=AF_INET;
address.sin_port=htons(15000);
inet_pton(AF_INET,argv[1],&address.sin_addr);



    if(connect(create_socket,(struct sockaddr*)&address,sizeof(address))==0)
    printf("%s connected\n",argv[1]);
    else
    printf("not connected\n");

    printf("Enter the filename\n");
    scanf("%s",fname);
    send(create_socket,fname,strlen(fname),0);

    printf("get the values");

        while(n=recv(create_socket,buffer,bufsize,0)>0)
        write(1,buffer,n);



return close(create_socket);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the information provided, two problems with transmitting the file name are apparent:

(1) You do not check the return value of send. You cannot be sure what is sent.

(2) You choose not to send the terminating '\0' over the network. Therefore, the receiver has no way of determining when the complete file name has been received. The receiver also does not check the return value of recv. Additionally, the receiver does not bother to terminate the received filename with a '\0'.